# How to maximize window programatically in Spec (Pharo 3)

Tags: user-interface, smalltalk, pharo

[Documentation](https://github.com/spec-framework/documentation/blob/master/output/book.md) does not describe how to maximize a window when its opened. API suggests that

```
aComposableModel containingWindow maximize.
aComposableModel window maximize.
```

but none of them works. Is there a way to maximize a recently opened Window?

Comment: If Ben answered your question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the delay.
I answered two days ago, but it seems it did not work :S

So now in Pharo this feature is not supported.
A workaround is:

```
m := TextModel new openWithSpec.
m widget widget maximize.
```

**Note**: accessing via `widget` is really bad (and will be deprecated soon).

But since you asked it, and it's actually something missing, this feature has been integrated into the [bleeding edge](http://benjamin.is-a-geek.com:9095/job/Spec/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/Spec.zip) version of Spec.
So now you can do:

```
m := TextModel new openWithSpec.
m maximize.
```

The next sync between Spec and Pharo will bring this feature into Pharo.